# Python storing variable instead of value

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I have been programming python for a while now, but somehow I have never been bothered by this problem. Whenever I store a variable in an array, I end up storing the actual *variable* and not the *value*. Here's what I mean:

```
var1 = [1]
arr1 = [var1]
arr1[0][0] = 2
print var1
```

The result I get from this is [2], even though I changed the value inside arr1 and not var1. It's as if var1 is being stored inside arr1, and not it's value, [1]. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: `var1` _points_ to a list. `arr1[0]` points to the same list.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

This is because you *are* changing var1. Python passes by reference, not by value, so you are changing the object itself.

Comment: Thank you. And Is there a way to pass the value, and not the reference, that doesn't require looping through the entire array?

Comment: Easiest way is to simply make a copy of var1 and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* actually storing a value. When you assign:

```
list_a = [1]
```

the *value* of the variable `list_a` is a *reference* to the new list. Whenever you pass it around, you pass that reference as a value. So,

```
list_b = [list_a]
```

contains the reference to the original list, and `list_b[0][0] = 2` will modify it.